Strong duality in cone programming
In pg 53 of Lectures in modern convex optimization, an assumption is made for the following cone program
$$\begin{align}
&\min c^Tx \\
&Ax - b {\geq}_{K} 0,
\end{align} $$
where $K$ is a cone, that $A$ is a full rank matrix. The author states that this is to ensure that $c \in Im (A^T)$ and then argues that if this does not hold true, then the above problem is either unbounded or infeasible. A similar assumption is also discussed for semidefinite programming.   Although I understand the mathematical reasoning behind it (given in pg 53), I am unable to get how important this assumption is. Other books (including convex optimization by Boyd) or other lecture notes, do not explicitly write this assumption. As far as I know, slater's condition (strict feasbility) is gives strong duality for convex programs. then why this assumption is being made? Can we just do away with this? Also I am trying to implement an SOCP problem in Python. It makes me wonder, do I need to ensure that this assumption is satisfied for all the parameters (like A and c) that I fix in my code?
